# Cartoon where main character merges with alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

All I remember that the alien had three forms: one shoots fire, another is strong and I think the last one was fast.

There was an episode where the alien friend of the main character reads superhero comics and creates a new form for the main character where it is muscular and has a cape.

Another episode they worked with a director and he asked for food with diamonds and they heated up rocks and put pressure on it to turn it into diamond.

The final episode the alien almost sacrificed itself but he survived, when the main character asked him "Are you ok? Say something" he said "Something."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you see this?  Did the alien's forms have distinctive colours?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Comment: Black cyan and white, and no name comes to mind